# Multiple bar charts with 2D Array

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I want to generate three different barcharts for each element of "dataArray". This is what I've done so far. plz help me.

```
var dataArray = [[40, 60], [70, 90], [100, 180]];

var canvas = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 1000)
.attr("height", 1000);

var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataArray[0])
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", function(d){return d;})
            .attr("height",50)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function(d,i){return i*100;});
```

Comment: See e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/kpq/6695897

Comment: Dat's simple, I uderstood,  now please help me out here to adjust some function property in attr("width",...) and data(dataArray[...]), so that I can generate within these line of codes. @LarsKotthoff